# Referencing a nuget package create by an asp.net 5 class library from a Win Forms app targeting .Net 4.0 Client Profile

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I have a asp.net 5 class library containing an object model that I need to share with a WinForms application targeting .Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile.

I have created a Nuget Package from the asp.net 5 class library and tried referencing this NuGet package from the WinForms application. However when adding the referece i get the following error:

> Could not install package 'package name 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I tried adding DNX40 as a target framework in the "frameworks" section of my project.json file as shown below.

```
{
  "authors": [ "author" ],
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "description": "Shared object models",
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx40": { },
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-22816",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-22816"
      }
    }
  },
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "projectUrl": "",
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

I suspect that I'm targeting the wrong framework version.

But how do I specify .Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile as the target framework? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `net40`:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net40": {},
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {}
 }
```

Here are some possible combinations: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/b0c5920b8ff0a96cac2446b1aeb8a80b3069c2ab/test/Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Tests/VersionUtilityFacts.cs